# Ipopt not triggering termination when all criterions are met

Tags: ipopt

The title almost explains it all.
I am using Ipopt'Java interface on a complex tool to optimize space trajectories. For some problems, Ipopt works as expected. But for some others, I can't make it trigger termination whereas it finds a near-optimal solution and all tolerances seem satisfied to me. Is there a hidden criterion I am missing?
I trigger termination using the max_iter criterion, but I would like to avoid this kind of manipulation to a potential user.
I can't detail the optimization problem, as there is a huge back end to manage my flight dynamics.
Any suggestions?

Here is Ipopt's output:

[image: Ipopt's output]

And here are my Ipopt tolerances options:

```
    singleShooting.setIntegerOption("max_iter", 8); 
    singleShooting.setNumericOption("tol", 0.001);
    singleShooting.setNumericOption("constr_viol_tol", 0.0005);
    singleShooting.setNumericOption("dual_inf_tol", 1); 
    singleShooting.setNumericOption("compl_inf_tol", 0.01);
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

`inf_pr` and `inf_du` from the log do not provide all values that are necessary to evaluate the stopping criterion on Ipopt. There are both scaled and unscaled violations of primal, dual, and complementarity constraints and an overall NLP error.
See https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OUTPUT.html regarding the meaning of `inf_pr` and `inf_du`.

By setting the Ipopt option `print_level` to 6 (or higher), you get all necessary quantities, e.g.,

```
***Current NLP Values for Iteration 7:

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   1.7014017031783709e+01    1.7014017031783709e+01
Dual infeasibility......:   2.1824331272373404e-07    2.1824331272373404e-07
Constraint violation....:   2.7626678900105617e-07    2.7626678900105617e-07
Complementarity.........:   1.0473361552873725e-07    1.0473361552873725e-07
Overall NLP error.......:   2.7626678900105617e-07    2.7626678900105617e-07
```

As described in https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html#OPT_Termination, `tol` applies to the scaled overall NLP error, while `constr_viol_tol`, `dual_inf_tol`, and `compl_inf_tol` apply to the constraint violation (aka primal infeasibility), dual infeasibility, and violation of complementarity of the unscaled problem. So the latter three let you specify some mimimal requirements on the feasibility and optimality of the problem as you see it, while `tol` can be used to guide how much effort should be spend into solving the problem as Ipopt sees it.

In case someone wants to look deeper what is going on, the termination check is implemented at
https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/blob/stable/3.14/src/Algorithm/IpOptErrorConvCheck.cpp#L208